# Popup window get value and clear while close it

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have alert pop up window on dblclick of textbox. I have a text area inside pop up window, I want to store the value entered in popup window in temporary variable and close popup window. Is it possible  to store the data temporary and also clear the data once popup window is closed by user. because for multiple textboxes have same alert window.

```
var opt = {
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 350,
            height: 'auto',
            title: 'Comments'
        };

        $(function () {
            $("#Cmnts").dialog({
                autoOpen: false                
            });
        });
     $(document).ready(function () {
                    var theDialog = $("#Cmnts").dialog(opt);
                    $("input[type='text']").on("dblclick", function () {
                        $('#Cmnts').dialog('open');
             });
        });

    <div id="Cmnts" style="display:none;">
            <textarea name="Cmnts" id="CmntsTxt" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
     </div>
```

can anyone help me to solve this
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below code in `ready`

```
$("#Cmnts").on('dialogclose', function(event) {
    $("#dialogValue").val($('#CmntsTxt').val())
    $('#CmntsTxt').val('');
});
```

Add HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="dialogValue">
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/pzmLkp1d/1/)

Comment: Hi Rejith Thanks for your reply. Now i got it I can able to get data entered in pop up window while close it. But i want to store the data in hiddenfield or some variable and also clear it from popup once i stored in another variable/close popup window.